# jQuery Toggle img inside a label

Tags: jquery, css, html, toggle

I think i have a simple problem.

I am trying to create a simple expand and collapse panel using .toggle.

Although the content expands and collapses as expected, i am trying to place some icons to help the user, i cannot get these images to toggle too.

HTML:

```
<div class="toggle_head Header">
    <label>
        <img height="30px"; src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/2338/reflection/128/expand_alt.png" />
    </label>
    <label class="hide">
        <img height="30px"; src="http://png-2.findicons.com/files/icons/2338/reflection/128/collapse_alt.png" />
    </label>
    <label>Expand</label>
</div>
<div class="toggle_body">
    <label>My content</label>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".toggle_body").hide();
$(".collapse").hide();

$(".toggle_head").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.next(".toggle_body").slideToggle("slow", function () {
        $this.children('img').toggle();            
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.Header {
    background: #DADADA;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #DADADA), color-stop(100%, #DADADA));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#DADADA, #DADADA);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#DADADA, #DADADA);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#DADADA, #DADADA);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#DADADA, #DADADA);
    color: #5C5C5C;
    height: 45px;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/2ZP9v/3/

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `img` are not direct descendant of `.toggle_head`, for this purpose use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead:

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched
>   elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Code:

```
$(".toggle_body").hide();
$(".collapse").hide();

$(".toggle_head").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.next(".toggle_body").slideToggle("slow", function () {
        $this.find('img').toggle();
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZP9v/4/

Comment: Thanks! That solves it! What if i have a question mark like http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/2ZP9v/8/, can i stop that from dissappearing on click?

Comment: @OamPsy just add a class to the expand/collpse icons and use them in your selector, like: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZP9v/9/

Answer (score 0):

--------JQuery Code---------

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

     $(".toggle_body").hide();
    $(".collapse").hide();


    $(".toggle_head").click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.next(".toggle_body").slideToggle("slow", function () {
            $this.find('img').toggle();
        });
    });

 });

</script>
```

-----------UI Code----------------

```
<div class="toggle_head Header">
    <label>
        <img height="30px" src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/2338/reflection/128/expand_alt.png" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <img class="hide" height="30px" src="http://png-2.findicons.com/files/icons/2338/reflection/128/collapse_alt.png" />
    </label>
    <label>Expand</label>
</div>
<div class="toggle_body">
    <label>My content</label>
</div>
```